# キッチリした性格の人 >>What does this mean about a person characteristic?

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

Context : 2 character are talking ,they're seems to be the student at a magic school

C2: あ、あはは…なんか、ここって愉快な人が多いのかしら。ちょっと思ってた感じとは違うなあ

C1: もっと**キッチリした性格の人**とか、捻くれた魔術士ばっかりだと思ってた?

Later on C2 thanks C1 ,because she said will guide C2 around the school and introducing her to people C1 knows about

C1: お礼は食堂のスィーツでいい

C2: あ、そういうところは**キッチリ**してるんだ

What does this expression mean about one person's personality ?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context, きっちり could be translated as “tight”, “exact”, “punctual”, “proper”, etc.

If someone is described as キッチリした性格の人, she would most likely be dressed neatly, keep things well organized, make plans meticulously, follow rules strictly, never be late to appointments, etc. In short, she is the opposite of いい加減な人.

As C2 has learned, C1 and her colleagues are not that kind of people. Yet she didn’t forget to ask for a reward for her small favor to C2. C2 saw キッチリ-ness in that.

Answer (score 2):

As C1 wants to get sweets for the reward of showing around a magic school.

It depends on the way of C2 saying though, it should be “shrewd” or “calculating” for the magicians‘ personality.

Probably “shrewd” fits in the context since “捻くれた“ has been used after that.